# Flask - Jquery Load Images from Database

Tags: jquery, ajax, flask

I have all my image path stored in Database

In the Database it is stored as
"templates/assets/userdata/visitorimages/4f686593-2c5a-4d9c-b3d9-ad389b3df690.jpg"

My Flask Code

```
  @visitor_management.route("/getallVisits",methods=['POST'])
```

def getallVisits():
response={"data":visitor_management_model.getallVisits(),"message":"visits fetched successfully !"}
return json.dumps(response)

Model

```
def getallVisits():
try:
    query="SELECT v.visit_id,v.purpose_of_visit,l.name,IF(v.authorized_by=0,'UNAUTHORISED',a.name),v.visitor_info,v.`status`,v.visitor_photo FROM visit v LEFT JOIN locations l ON v.location = l.id  LEFT JOIN admin a ON a.id = v.authorized_by"
    #query="select visit_id,purpose_of_visit,location,authorized_by,resident_id,status from visit order by in_time desc"
    cur.execute(query)
    output = cur.fetchall()
    return output
except Exception:
    return False
```

Javascript / Jquery Snippet where the Image is supposed to be loaded

```
tableData += '<td class="authorizedClass"> <img src="{{url_for("static",filename="'+output[i][6]+'"}}"  /> </td>';
```

The I get the following error on the browser console.

```
GET http://localhost:5000/assets/%27%2Boutput%5Bi%5D%5B6%5D%2B%27 404 (NOT FOUND)
```

Comment: I would start with checking what is returned in the JSON response to make sure the value is what you're expecting. If that doesn't look right, check what you're getting from the database.

Comment: From the database I am getting the path of the image.